# Import CSV into SQL (CODE)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to import several CSV files automatically using SQL-code (i.e. without using the GUI). Normally, I know the dimensions of my CSV file. So, in many cases I create an empty table with, let say, `x` columns with the corresponding data types. Then, I import the CSV file into this table using `BULK INSERT`. However, in this case I don't know much about my files, i.e. information about data types and dimensions are not given.

To summerize the problem:

> I receive a file path, e.g. C:...\DATA.csv. Then, I want to use this path in SQL-code to import the file to a table without knowing anything about it.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't, the csv and the table columns have to match exactly. If you don't know the dimensions, you're not going to be able to define the target table. If you **must**, you could try to insert it all into a one-column table, and try to extract the columns from there. But you should probably write a clever tool for this.

Comment: I have stopped trying to use SQL to import CSV files and I have switched to Powershell. IMHO is simply an easier way to accomplish this task and I can leverage my .Net skills.

Comment: @MarkKram That sounds promising, however I don't know much about Powershell tbh. Is this a built-in function? Are there any examples I can use to realise this in PS?

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/fast-csv-import-in-powershell-to-sql-server

Comment: This, `Then, I want to use this path in SQL-code to import the file to a table without knowing anything about it.` appears to be an example of wanting to write code without knowing what it's supposed to accomplish.

Comment: You could also look into the openrowset select, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @DanBracuk I must admit that it is indeed a bit general. The main goal, however, is clear I suppose? That is, to write SQL code, which imports csv data into a table independent of its dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this:

```
BULK INSERT tbl
FROM 'csv_full_path'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2, --Second row if header row in file
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'error_file_path',
TABLOCK
)
```

If columns are not known, you could try with:

```
select * from OpenRowset
```

Or, do a bulk insert with only the first row as one big column, then parse it to create the dynamic main insert. Or bulk insert the whole file into a table with just one column, then parse that...

Comment: Thx; however, this code requires me to create table tbl beforehand, right? Can I do this automatically without creating a table manually for each CSV file?

Comment: You could do it dynamically, I added some suggestions.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how to parse a one big column. This solution sounds very intresting and it might solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it should solve your problem. Use tsql substring and charindex functions. There are plenty of examples around. Or string_split function on 2016 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OPENROWSET` ([documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)).

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.MyTable
FROM 
OPENROWSET(
   BULK 'C:\...\mycsvfile.csv',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS DATA;
```

In addition, you can use dynamic SQL to parameterize table name and location of csv file.